# Cover the callback argument inside custom hook with Jest/Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme, test-coverage

I have a functional component that i want to test it and i use the scroll position hook (plugin @n8tb1t/use-scroll-position) to get Y by passing callback argument. But i see that my test is not covering the callback of the scroll position hook.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useScrollPosition } from '@n8tb1t/use-scroll-position';

const Scroll = (): JSX.Element => {
    const [y, setY] = useState(0);

    useScrollPosition(({ currPos }): void => {
        setY(Math.abs(currPos.y));
    });

    return (
        <>
            <style jsx global>{`
                .parent {
                    position: relative;
                }

                .y {
                    position: fixed;
                    top: 1em;
                    right: 1em;
                    background-color: #fff;
                    padding: 2em;
                    border: 5px solid #000;
                }

                .p {
                    height: 1500px;
                    padding: 2em;
                }
            `}</style>
            <div id="parent" className="parent">
                <b className="y">Y {y}px</b>
                <p className="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nostrum molestias architecto quam assumenda error enim ab quia animi placeat dolor.</p>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Scroll;
```

This is the coverage results of my component:

[image: coverage]

I'm new in testing, i don't know how to cover it. What i know, i can't spy on it because the function is private. i tried the mock implementation nothing change!

This is test file that i made:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import Scroll from '@src/pages/scroll';
import { waitForComponentToPaint } from '@src/__mocks__/act';

afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
});

describe('Scroll Component', () => {
    it('Should render without throwing an error', async () => {
        const wrap = shallow(<Scroll />);
        await waitForComponentToPaint(wrap);

        expect(wrap.find('#parent')).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

In my project, i use Next.js as framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to cover the callback argument of custom hook, you just need to configure a mock by implementing the function like that:

```
jest.mock('@n8tb1t/use-scroll-position', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('@n8tb1t/use-scroll-position'),
    useScrollPosition: jest.fn()
        .mockImplementationOnce((cb) => cb({ currPos: { y: 200 } })),
}));
```